# Storage space usage for a blob

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to find out the actual space usage in Azure Storage for a Blob with snapshots. As the charges accrued against storing snapshots is dictated by the block-level changes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh768807.aspx), what I am trying to find out is "is there an optimization in storage?", if so what is the optimization. Let us suppose the size of the blob is 1 MB and snapshot is also 750 KB. The total size i can fetch is 1 MB + 750 KB, but the charge may accrued for 1 MB assuming that the 750 KB are unchanged between blobs. How do I know the actual size?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of finding this out for a single blob. We provide billable storage size only for the entire storage account through the [storage metrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343258.aspx).